# .htaccess language subdomain redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to redirect my language variables **domain.com?lang=X** to subdomains **X.domain.com**

I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=(es|de|fi|tr)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately, when I want to change language by going to **domain.com/page?lang=es**, I'm redirected to **es.domain.com/page?lang=es** which causes a loop.

So I tried adding a questionmark to the end of the URL like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

to prevent it from adding the **?lang=** variable when accessed by the subdomain but in that case the language doesn't change and I end up with **es.domain.com/page** in English.

I've spent the last 4 hours digging through StackOverflow and other sites trying to find a solution but to no avail. How can I detect that I'm already redirected to the subdomain and then ignore the **?lang=** variable while actually changing the language?

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need 2 rules for this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect rule using THE_REQUEST variable
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]*)\?&?lang=(es|de|fi|tr)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%2.domain.com/%1? [NE,R=301,L]

# internal rewrite rule to add lang parameter back
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(es|de|fi|tr)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The last rule that adds the lang parameter causes a loop because I end up with es.domain.com/page?lang=es the subdomain and ?lang= both redirect to each other.

Comment: It only works for the home page, e.g es.domain.com. If I go to es.domain.com/1/2, it loops as es.domain.com/1/2?lang=es

Comment: I get twenty one 301 redirects for es.domain.com/1/2?lang=es

Comment: Can you please try my updated answer after completely clearing browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following .htaccess Rules at the top of your htaccess file.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##use THE_REQUEST variable to match condition here, with NC flag.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^?]*)\?&?lang=(es|de|fi|tr)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%2.domain.com%1 [NE,R=301,L]
```